# Can't find Boost building CGAL example

Tags: boost, cmake, cgal

I'm trying to build a particular example that came with CGAL but it fails to find BOOST for some reason.
I successfully compiled CGAL itself in a similar manner.
I followed [this guide on how to build it on windows](http://www.cgal.org/windows_installation.html#CompilinganExample).

I'm sure setted up BOOST_ROOT environment variable correctly.

**Edit2**: I recreated cmake file with given script for Core example as follows.

> cd temp
>
> cgal_create_CMakeLists -s delunay

In cmake UI I set Boost_DEBUG=ON and Configure.

I get error as follows (I've edited out irrelevant parts):

```
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:476 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.1;/* ... omitted*/
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:478 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:480 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = OFF
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:482 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:484 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 1.56.1; /*... omitted*/
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:486 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:538 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:540 ]   BOOST_ROOT = 
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:542 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = 
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:544 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = 
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:546 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.1;1.56.0; /*... omitted*/
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:639 ] location of version.hpp: D:/dev/boost_1_54_0/boost/version.hpp
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:663 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.54.0
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:739 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -vc110
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:749 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:792 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:794 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -gd
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:842 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = D:/dev/boost_1_54_0/lib32-msvc-11.0;D:/dev/boost_1_54_0/lib;D:/dev/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib;D:/dev/boost_1_54_0/lib;D:/dev/boost_1_54_0/../lib;D:/dev/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib
cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1017 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
Boost version: 1.54.0
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory D:/dev/CGAL-4.3/scripts/temp

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/dev/CGAL-4.3/scripts/temp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Core's generated cmake file:

```
# Created by the script cgal_create_cmake_script_with_options
# This is the CMake script for compiling a set of CGAL applications.

project( delaunay )


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.2)
if("${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}" VERSION_GREATER 2.6)
  if("${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_PATCH_VERSION}" VERSION_GREATER 2.8.3)
    cmake_policy(VERSION 2.8.4)
  else()
    cmake_policy(VERSION 2.6)
  endif()
endif()

set( CMAKE_ALLOW_LOOSE_LOOP_CONSTRUCTS true )
 
if ( COMMAND cmake_policy )

  cmake_policy( SET CMP0003 NEW )  

endif()

# CGAL and its components
find_package( CGAL QUIET COMPONENTS  )

if ( NOT CGAL_FOUND )

  message(STATUS "This project requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.")
  return()  

endif()

# include helper file
include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )


# Boost and its components
find_package( Boost REQUIRED )

if ( NOT Boost_FOUND )

  message(STATUS "This project requires the Boost library, and will not be compiled.")

  return()  

endif()

# include for local directory

# include for local package
include_directories( BEFORE ../include )


# Creating entries for target: delaunay
# ############################

add_executable( delaunay  delaunay.cpp )

add_to_cached_list( CGAL_EXECUTABLE_TARGETS delaunay )

# Link the executable to CGAL and third-party libraries
target_link_libraries(delaunay   ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES} )
```

Anyone have a clue what could be wrong?

Comment: I suggest you create a CMake Boolean variable named "Boost_DEBUG" and set is to "ON", and re-configure. That variable will make the FindBoost script more verbose. Please copy the new CMake output.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking a look, please see my edit above.

Comment: You should be using `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` rather than `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}` in your `include_directories` call.  See the [docs for FindBoost](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/module/FindBoost.html) for further info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed that `CMakeLists.txt` does not try to find Boost libraries and headers. That is why the `Boost_DEBUG` variable has no effect. It seems that the CGAL libraries configuration was not correct. You should rerun CMake in your build directory of CGAL libraries, and check that there is no error.

Comment: See my edit. I regenerated the cmake file which now looks correct I think. But I ran into a slightly different problem.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you did. I told you that you should re-configure and re-build the CGAL libraries themselves. Is `D:/dev/CGAL-4.3/scripts/temp/build` a build directory of the CGAL libraries or one for a special example? What is the value of `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` in the `D:/dev/CGAL-4.3/scripts/temp/build/CMakeCache.txt`?